# HTML Helper for model binding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary, html-helper

I am writing a general purpose html helper that passes a dictionary back to my controller. (Perhaps this already exists?)

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Odometer(IDictionary<String, int> Odometers, String UserInputInJson)
    {
        ...
    }
```

and here is the helper as it stands now. It is working without the name (commented out).

**Helper:**

```
    public static MvcHtmlString EditorToSubmitDictionaryEntryFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> item, String key)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(item, helper.ViewData);
        string value = metadata.Model.ToString();
        // string name = metadata.PropertyName + "s"; // make it plural
        Type type = typeof(TProperty);

        // build the first hidden Index tag: <input name="Index" id="Index" type="hidden" value="1D6H983G3DL784930"/>
        var indexAnchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        indexAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", "Index");
        indexAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", "Index");
        indexAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
        indexAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", key);
        string indexAnchorHtml = indexAnchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // <input name="[1D6H983G3DL784930].Value" class="text-box single-line" type="number" value="12345"/>
        // <input name="Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930].Value" class="text-box single-line" id="Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930].Value" type="number" value="12345"/>
        var valueAnchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", /*name +*/ "["+ key +"].Value");
        valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", /*name +*/ "[" + key + "].Value");
        valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", "text-box single-line");
        if (type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(int?) || type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(double?) || type == typeof(decimal) || type == typeof(decimal?) || type == typeof(float) || type == typeof(float?))
            valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "number");
        else
            valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
        valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
        string valueAnchorHtml = valueAnchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // <input name="[1D6H983G3DL784930].Key" id="[1D6H983G3DL784930].Key" type="hidden" value="1D6H983G3DL784930"></input>"
        // <input name="Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930].Key" id="Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930].Key" type="hidden" value="1D6H983G3DL784930"></input>"
        var keyAnchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        keyAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", /*name +*/ "[" + key + "].Key");
        keyAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", /*name +*/ "[" + key + "].Key");
        keyAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
        keyAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", key);
        string keyAnchorHtml = keyAnchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(indexAnchorHtml + valueAnchorHtml + keyAnchorHtml);
    }
```

And here's how I'm calling this helper... in a view and a partial view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Odometer", "DEQToo", FormMethod.Post))
{
//this is here so we can keep track of what the user searched for, in case the session times out and we have to re-build the page.
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserInputInJson)
<table class="footable table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vCollect[""].Odometer)</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vCollect[""].VIN)</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet" data-type="numeric">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vCollect[""].VehicleYear)</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vCollect[""].Make)</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vCollect[""].Model)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (VehicleWithMostRecentTestOutput v in Model)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_OdometerRowPartial", v)
            }
        }
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="@DEQTooResource.resCorrectOdometer" id="OdometerListSubmit" />
}
```

And the partial view where I call EditorToSubmitDictionaryEntryFor():

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorToSubmitDictionaryEntryFor(model => model.Odometer, Model.VIN)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VIN) </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VehicleYear)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Make)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model)</td>
</tr>
```

I want to use the name so it will be more general purpose and I can have more than one of these on a page. When I un-comment name, adding it to the name and id attributes of both the key and value, then model state is invalid and I don't get user input passed in to the controller.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and give suggestions of what to do about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I will also take any suggestions on how to improve this helper. Thanks.

Comment: I take it you have set break point after 'string name = ...' and hover over the name variable to see what is being stored at run time? Is this any different to what you expect?

Comment: Yes. string name = Odometer. It is exactly what I expected.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Odometers?

Comment: Yep. Actually, I did put the "s" on the end, as it should be.

Comment: I was thinking that adding s is not the best. Maybe something like adding Dict so that the controller will have it's argument named FieldNameDict for example OdometerDict. I liked adding s because Odometer becomes Odometers and Name becomes Names. But then Fish becomes Fishs, not Fishes and Fox becomes Foxs, not Foxes which isn't quite right. Of course the real problem is that the data is not coming through and the model state is invalid. The name seems correct from an MVC convention perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just require something like:

```
valueAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", id + "["+ key +"]");
```

You just want `Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930]` without the `.Value`, not `Odometers[1D6H983G3DL784930].Value`

The Item property is another name for the indexer, so you can omit its name when accessing elements.

Comment: Thanks! That's a beautiful and simple answer, and exactly what I needed.